# How to conditionally redirect in a StreamBuilder, builder function in flutter without Error?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to get an auth form to conditionally redirect in a flutter StreamBuilder widget using a ternary statement.

When the redirect condition returns true I get a red screen and the following log:

```
I/flutter ( 3787): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3787): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 3787): _StreamBuilderBaseState<Map<dynamic, dynamic>, AsyncSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>#66400):
I/flutter ( 3787): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter ( 3787): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter ( 3787): process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
I/flutter ( 3787): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
I/flutter ( 3787): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
I/flutter ( 3787): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter ( 3787): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter ( 3787):   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#4f97a](state: OverlayState#5df28(tickers: tracking 2
I/flutter ( 3787):   tickers, entries: [OverlayEntry#09e48(opaque: false; maintainState: false),
I/flutter ( 3787):   OverlayEntry#61a61(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#79842(opaque: false;
I/flutter ( 3787):   maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#11ff2(opaque: false; maintainState: true)]))
I/flutter ( 3787): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
I/flutter ( 3787):   StreamBuilder<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<Map<dynamic, dynamic>,
I/flutter ( 3787):   AsyncSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>#66400)
```

Offending widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../blocs/auth_bloc.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final authBloc = AuthBloc();
  Map<String, bool> initialData = {'loginSuccess': false, 'isLoading': false};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authBloc.redirect,
        initialData: initialData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Scaffold(body: _render(context, snapshot));
        });
  }

  Widget _render(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return !snapshot.data['loginSuccess'] && snapshot.data['isLoading']
        ? _circularSpinner()
        : snapshot.data['loginSuccess'] && !snapshot.data['isLoading']
            ? _redirect(context)
            : _buildPage();
  }

  _redirect(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard');
  }

  Widget _buildPage() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _emailField(authBloc),
              _padding(),
              _passwordField(authBloc),
              _padding(),
              _submitButton(authBloc)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _circularSpinner() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  Widget _emailField(AuthBloc authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.email,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.emailChanged,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'you@example.com',
            labelText: 'Email Address',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _passwordField(AuthBloc authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.password,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.passwordChanged,
          obscureText: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: '8 characters or more with at least 1 number',
            labelText: 'Password',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _padding() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    );
  }

  Widget _submitButton(AuthBloc authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authBloc.submitValid,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Login'),
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: snapshot.hasError ? null : authBloc.submitForm,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I have googled but cannot find anything relating to Navigator in this context.

I expect the Widget to redirect to the 'dashboard' widget. Instead I get red error screen.

Comment: What is  `isLoading` for ? it's for getting some information before executing the loging ? or it's when then user has already clicked on Submit button and it's validating the credentials ?

Comment: It is for the state between a user clicking login and awaiting a response from the server. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

I run today into the same problem. I tried the solution from @user8467470 but StreamBuilder is already registered to my Stream. So I ended up with this solution:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<Response<ExchangeRate>>(
            stream: _bloc.exchangeDataStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                switch (snapshot.data.status) {
                  case Status.LOADING:
                    return LoadingWidget(loadingMessage: snapshot.data.message);
                  case Status.COMPLETED:
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
                    });
                    break;
                  case Status.ERROR:
                    return Container(
                      child: Text(snapshot.data.message),
                    );
                }
              }
              return Container();
            }));
  }
```

This way I have only one stream in my bloc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around but it isn't pretty. I thought I would share it here in case anyone else was having the same problem but I of course expect other more experienced Flutter devs to offer a better solution and rationale.

It seems that for whatever reason StreamBuilder does not like you Navigating away in the builder function due to its build flow. As a result I moved the navigate away outside of the StreamBuilder but inside the build method and added a listener like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Manually listening for redirect conidtions here
    // once a response is received from the server
    authBloc.loginSuccess.listen((data) {
      if (data) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard');
      }
    });

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authBloc.isLoading,
        initialData: false,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          return Scaffold(
            body: snapshot.data ? _circularSpinner() : _buildPage(),
          );
        });
  }
```

It seems to work now but will keep my eye on best practice for this.